# Python pwlf (piecewise linear functions) gives different results for the same data

Tags: python-3.x, regression, linear-regression, piecewise

This is my data:

```
x
array([  0,   7,  14,  21,  28,  35,  42,  49,  56,  63,  70,  77,  84,
        91,  98, 105, 112, 119, 126, 133, 140, 147, 154, 161, 168, 175])

y
array([0.4 , 0.4 , 0.4 , 0.4 , 0.6 , 0.6 , 0.6 , 0.6 , 0.6 , 0.97, 0.97,
       0.97, 0.97, 1.13, 1.13, 1.13, 1.13, 1.13, 0.9 , 0.9 , 0.9 , 0.9 ,
       0.7 , 0.7 , 0.7 , 0.7 ])
```

I applied `pwlf` - https://pypi.org/project/pwlf but I get different `fit_breaks` every time I execute this code:

```
pwlf_model = pwlf.PiecewiseLinFit(x, y ,degree=1)
pwlf_model.fit(4)
```

First run

```
pwlf_model.fit_breaks
array([  0.        ,  58.01861485,  60.07425168, 104.30868782,
       175.        ])
```

Second run

```
pwlf_model.fit_breaks
array([  0.        ,  59.48475228,  59.67460644, 104.30594173,
       175.        ])
```

Third run

```
pwlf_model.fit_breaks
array([  0.        ,  56.60204   ,  62.0270283 , 104.30827438,
       175.        ])
```

Fourth run

```
pwlf_model.fit_breaks
array([  0.        ,  58.92722066,  59.50363949, 104.30764284,
       175.        ])
```

Why is that? any randomized steps in the model?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iut9x.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the method used to do the fits is stochastic. From the [pwlf source code](https://github.com/cjekel/piecewise_linear_fit_py/blob/master/pwlf/pwlf.py), fit calls the function `scipy.optimize.differential_evolution`. The [Scipy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html) for this function describe it as a stochastic method to determine a global minimum of a function.

It appears that with the default settings used by pwlf, its not quite converged or at least its approaching convergence from different directions each time. You maybe able to edit the keywords so that the optimization will do a more stringent search for the true minimum. For example, `atol` sets the absolute tolerance for convergence. You also set `seed` to a consistent value to at least get the same result every time, even if it may not have found the "true" minimum. Just be aware that if you change one of the keywords, you need to explicitly write out all the others, as the `**kwargs` passed into `fit` appear to overwrite the defaults that would be passed to `differential_evolution`.

Comment: Thank you for that clear explanation, I'll try the different options